# how to make mm/dd/yyyy, 12:00 as html5 datetime-local initial value

Tags: html, datetime, datepicker

The initial value for `<input type='datetime-local'/>` is

[image]

I want to set the initial value of time part in the control to be 12:00

[image]

I tried `<input id ="x" type="datetime-local" step="86400"/>` to achieve it but the time part becomes read only.

[image]

Please suggest how to set initial value for time part in the datetime-local to 12:00.

Thanks.

Comment: I do not think you can because the set value needs to be valid, and since it is a `datetime-local` element a valid value needs both date and time parts

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Thanks. but can we change some attribute in the DOM to only modify the time part?

Comment: i think your best option is to use a `date` input and a `time` input side by side. Something like https://jsfiddle.net/e4sktxLb/